# How to instrument a controller in nestjs interceptor?

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs, nestjs, datadog

I want to instrument every method of a nestjs controller for APM purposes.
I wrote the following interceptor in order to instrument the controller invocation.

However, I do not know how to properly wrap the call to `next.handle()`.
I do not have any experience using RxJS Observables.

Question: Is it possible to wrap the invocation properly and if so how?

The current approach seems to measure the controller's execution time but does not set a correct tracer scope for the controller's method. I guess the issue is that `next.handle()` must be wrapped too.

```js
import { CallHandler, ExecutionContext, Injectable, NestInterceptor } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Reflector } from "@nestjs/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { PATH_METADATA } from '@nestjs/common/constants';
import tracer from "dd-trace";

@Injectable()
export class ApmInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {}
    
    public intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<unknown> {
        const request: Request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

        const path = this.reflector.get<string[]>(PATH_METADATA, context.getHandler()); 
        const method = request.method;

        const observable = next.handle();

        tracer.trace(`[${method}] ${path}`, () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            observable.subscribe({
                complete: resolve,
            });
        }));

        return observable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you mean by instrument?

Comment: Sure, by instrumenting I mean: tracing the function execution to determine the execution time (as defined by e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_(computer_programming)) and provided by APM solutions such as e.g. https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/guide/instrument_custom_method/?tab=nodejs

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, haven't ever worked with `dd-trace`, but I do have [a custom logger](https://github.com/jmcdo29/ogma) with a Logging Interceptor that can output data in a DataDog friendly format. I'll look into `dd-trace` in the meantime

Comment: Long shot here, but I think what you'll want instead of `observable.subscribe()` is to do `observable.pipe(tap(resolve))` where `tap` is imported from `rxjs/operators`. If this works, I'll write a detailed explanation for the answer

Comment: Thanks for helping me out here @jay. However, I cannot get this to work since when I replace the line with observable.subscribe with observable.pipe, the tap's callback is not invoked at all. I guess that is because it is wrapped by the (async) tracer.trace method which delays something. If I add the .pipe to the next.handle() line it is invoked as expected but not wrapped by the tracer anymore. This seems to be tricky.

Comment: Interesting. Definitely feels like it's a problem of keeping the observable instance as expected while being able to tack on extra pipe calls as necessary.If you can provide access to the repository, I'd love to be able to give this a shot, I understand if you can't though. I may try to come up with something similar

Comment: it's looking like [even with basic callbacks and promises](https://runkit.com/embed/5ieiu1x0sijo) this isn't working,so it looks like it's less of how Nest works and more of how RxJS Observables work

Comment: Unfortunately it's a bit complicated for me to provide more context because the class above is part of a huge internal repo - sorry for that! However, I see you reproduced the scenario correctly using runkit - thanks! Do you think this is a conceptual issue with nestjs interceptors and they are simply not designed to provide a way to wrap the rxjs stuff? (honestly I still have no idea how the observable/observer code flow looks like under the hood)

Comment: I wouldn't quite say it's an issue with Nest, more like it's an issue with RxJS because of how _it's_ designed. The fact that Nest uses it does make it unfortunate in this case, though. I think what you'd have to do in this case is create a custom `Span` object from `d-trace` and set values as you'd expect. The custom logger I mentioned in an earlier comment kinda does this (without me knowing I did it) so you may be able to get some ideas from it. If you want to discuss this more, feel free to [reach out on Discord](https://discord.gg/nestjs). Username: `PerfectOrphan31#6003`

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue using [OpenTelemetry-js](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js), in order to set the correct scope I've to wrap the `handle()` `Observable` into an `Async` promise to set the context, and then wrap the promise again as `Observable` for the `rxjs` pipeline (`Observable` -> `Promise` -> `Observable`)

```
import {from, Observable} from 'rxjs';
...

 async intercept(executionContext: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Promise<Observable<any>> {
    const request: Request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

    const path = this.reflector.get<string[]>(PATH_METADATA, context.getHandler()); 
    const method = request.method;

    const observable = tracer.trace(`[${method}] ${path}`, () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return next.handle().toPromise();
    }));
    return observable.pipe(
        map(value => {
          // Here you can stop your trace manually
          return value;
        }),
        catchError(error => {
          // Here you can stop your trace manually
          throw error;
        }))
}
```

For OpenTelemetry you have to create/stop the span and set the correct context:

```
const span = trace.getTracer('default').startSpan(spanName);
const observable = from(context.with(trace.setSpan(context.active(), span), async () => {
  return next.handle().toPromise();
}));
return observable.pipe(
    map(value => {
      span.stop();
      return value;
    }),
    catchError(error => {
      span.addEvent('error', {error: error});
      span.stop();
      throw error;
    }))
```